# System.ArgumentException Invalid file name in Assembly.LoadModule(string,byte[])

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

During my studies of reflection, I have encountered the .net module.

I understand that means I can compile a single class as .net module (correct me if I wrong) then load this compiled .net module using Assembly.LoadModule(string,byte[]).

I wrote a class that look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Mycs {
    public static string GiveString(){
        return "Hello World !";
    }
}
```

and compiled it using the switch "/target:module" using this code:

```
CodeDomProvider CDP = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
CompilerParameters CP = new CompilerParameters();
CP.GenerateExecutable = false;
CP.CompilerOptions = "/target:module";
CP.OutputAssembly = FilePathText.Text.Replace(Strings.Right(FilePathText.Text, 3), ".netmodule");
string source = File.ReadAllText(FilePathText.Text);
CompilerResults RS = CDP.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CP, source);
```

I then retrieved the resulted file bytes:

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePathText.Text);
```

And finally I tried to load the module to the current executed assembly:

```
Module[] Modules = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules();
Module[] moduless = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetLoadedModules();
Module A = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().LoadModule(Modules[0].Name, b);
```

Whether I passed the `Modules[0].Name` or `moduless[0].Name` both cause this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid file name

Why do I get this invalid file name error?

Comment: And if you print `Modules[0].Name` what do you see?

Comment: executable file name "myfile.exe"

Comment: [moduleName: The name of the module. This string must correspond to a file name in this assembly's manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5713xtes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how can I define "string correspond to a file name" in current executed assembly manifest ?

Comment: it's something like "adding module in runtime using array of bytes from .netmodule file which exist in the hard disk " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load dynamically created module to an existing assembly, assemblies once compiled are immutable.

My best guess is that you need to use AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule() to create your classes in it. In this case you the type you created will be loaded automatically. or compile your classes as assemblies, not the modules, and load those assemblies dynamically using Assembly.LoadFile method.

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamically created module" ? I thought module is just like single piece of assembly and we can add this single piece to an existing assembly, can you please tell me what exactly is "module"?